# Returning records not related to a relationship?

Tags: php, model, controller, laravel, eloquent

What is the recommended Laravel way to return all records not in a relationship? What I mean by this is return all users that are not assigned to a task. I want to provide a drop down that shows all of these users so they can be assigned to the task. It would basically be the inverse of:

```
Task::find(1)->users()->get();
```

Thank you.

Table structure is as follows:

**users:**

```
user_id
email
password
```

*belongsToMany tasks*

**task_user**

```
task_id
user_id
```

**tasks**

```
task_id
task
```

*belongsToMany users*

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this from the user model (since the Task wont know about users that dont have tasks).

[Laravel provides a way to query relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) - so you could do something like this:

```
$users = User::has('task', '=', 0)->get();
```

edit - if you need specific tasks use a closure:

```
$users = new User;

$array = $users->with(array('tasks' => function($query)
{
    $query->where(task_id', 'whatever_task_you_want_here);
}))->get();

var_dump($array->toArray());
```

Comment: This makes sense but how would I do this for a specific task and not all tasks?

Comment: ummm... try including a ->where('task', 'cleaning') on the query - but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: That's looking for a column name of task and a value of cleaning, which doesn't work.

Comment: but on which table is it look for that column? on the user table, or the task table?

Comment: i've editted my answer. the code is not tested - but you get the idea

Comment: @Dalyn, can you show us the structure of your two tables (users and tasks)? That will help us answer the question.

Comment: Your updated code is returning all users, no matter their relationship to tasks. If I put a task ID in it just doesn't return that task in the nested tasks array on each user record.

Comment: @fideloper I have updated my question with the table structure.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to query relationship like that in Laravel 3.x?